# query is not showing result on HTML page but working perfectly in command line

Tags: php, html

//connection is set and working properly. 
here is the code for the database query which I am using. The same query is working fine for the command line but not displaying result on the HTML page.

```
$classname = $_GET['c'];
$mochildname = ltrim($_GET['q']);
$var1 = strtolower(preg_replace('/(.)([A-Z])/', '$1_$2', $mochildname));

$result = explode(":",$classname);
$result = array_reverse($result);
$moparent = array_pop($result);
$moname = implode(":",$result);


$sql = "SELECT * FROM MOList WHERE (MO_PARENT LIKE '%" . $moname . "' AND MO_NAME LIKE '%" . $var1 ."%')";

$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

$row = mysql_fetch_array($retval);
$mo_props = explode(',',$row[MO_PROPERTIES]);
for($i=0;$i<count($mo_props);$i++)
{

echo "<label class='$mo_props[$i]' style='display:block' >".$mo_props[$i]." : <input type='text' class='inputs' onkeyup='storevalues_mochilds(current_elem)' value=''></label>";
}
```

Comment: what is the value of "MO_PROPERTIES"? print $mo_props, is it containing data? what is the value of $var1?

Comment: Where is defined constant `MO_PROPERTIES` that you use in `explode(',',$row[MO_PROPERTIES]);`?

Comment: MO_PROPERTIES is in the table. the query is working perfectly fine if I hard code the value of var1 but not working if I pass the variable. I mean the HtML page is also displaying correct values, if I hard code the var1.

Comment: And I have checked the variable var1 is giving proper values.

Comment: try to echo the sql in browser,& try that from cmd

Answer (score 0):

Try

`$row["MO_PROPERTIES"]` rather than `$row[MO_PROPERTIES]`

See if that makes any difference

Comment: As all are in caps, may be this is custom defined variable & if you put it double quote, it will not return  the actual value.

Comment: But as the asker said, **'MO_PROPERTIES is in the table.'**